# Legal repercussions for an act of discrimination

Tags: united-states, discrimination

What are possible legal repercussions for someone who stands up in a restaurant and says something like "this n-r must leave the place where white people eat"? What laws apply here?

Comment: The someone is a patron, not an owner or employee, correct?

Comment: @Damila yes, a patron.

Comment: That's bigotry (which is not illegal) not discrimination, which afaik private citizens cannot do to each other under the legal definition. If calling someone *that* isn't libel or slander, then you're SoL. - *What can I do if someone does some racist shit?* Leave.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only applicable law is the local trespassing law. If he wants, the proprietor can demand that the patron leave, and if the patron does not leave, he can be arrested for trespassing. It uncontroversial that the First Amendment protects racist declarations.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. Does anything change if we're talking about peer coworkers in a company?

Comment: The employer will have to address this to prevent recurrences, otherwise they might be held liable for having a discriminatory employment policy, but that may involve some iffy legal analysis.

Comment: but the employee who did this isn't responsible before the law?

Comment: No, because the employment discrimination laws regulate the business, not the employee (or customer).

Comment: "It uncontroversial" did we miss out a word there?

Comment: @user855286 Not criminally. I suppose the owner could sue them for the loss of business but it's unlikely to be worth it.

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim Assuming it does cause loss of business. There are probably areas where it would attract like-minded customers.

Comment: If this was an expensive restaurant, I paid $500 for a meal for myself and my family, and obviously didn’t enjoy it because of this person, can I sue them for damages? If I’m (understandably) very upset and act against my usual peaceful nature, what could I legally get away with? If I recorded this outburst on my phone camera, how far could I publish it?

Comment: So if you have a disability it's your employers role under law to ensure other employees don't discriminate against you. That's interesting. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

In England, this action* would be a breach of the [Criminal Justice and Public Order Act (1994)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criminal_Justice_and_Public_Order_Act_1994), specifically that...

> A person is guilty of an offence if, **with intent to cause a person harassment**, alarm or distress, he ... uses threatening, **abusive or insulting words** or behaviour ... thereby **causing that or another person harassment**, alarm or distress.

As to punishment, this would be determined by a judge based on a number of factors, but not to exceed

> imprisonment for a term not exceeding six months or to a fine not exceeding level 5 on the standard scale [e.g. unlimited] or to both.

---

<sub><sup>*Noting that this is not 'discrimination', but rather 'abusive behaviour'</sup></sub>